# IE Address bar search. I need to add a list of other results at the end of current result list

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, search, bho, address-bar

Currently, if you type in the address bar in IE, you see a dropdown list of url search results depending on what you type.
I'd like any hint, anything, about **how to access the address bar object throught a BHO in C++**, so that
i can **append url results from my bho at the end the current list**.
Thank you.
*If anyone need precisions, please ask. I'll be checking for responses every single days.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this.  You can add your urls to History using IUrlHistoryStg, and then they will show up if they match what the user types.

Comment: I saw that in windows registry, under 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\TypedURLs' there is the list used by the address bar during typing. Do you think it would be a good idea to just manage my own list by writing in that registry so that i get my added url list ?

Comment: You could try that, but you never know when IE will cache the list instead of reading it.  Also it may not be possible to write to the necessary registry key from a low rights IE instance.